# tcpdump suppress console output in script & write to file

Tags: bash, tcpdump

In a bash script I need to run a tcpdump command and save the output to a file however when I do that via `> /tmp/test.txt` i still get the following output in the console:

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 1500 bytes
1 packet captured
1 packet received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

However I do wnat the script to wait for the command to complete before continuing.

is it possible to supress this output?

Comment: Looks like you are running `tcpdump` with the `-v` flag (verbose output). Might want to consider dropping the `-v` flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output you're seeing is written to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so you can redirect it to `/dev/null` if you don't want to see it.  For example:

```
 tcpdump -nn -v -i eth0 -s 1500 -c 1 'ether proto 0x88cc' > /tmp/test.txt 2> /dev/null
```